# How can I broadcast and event with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am using:

```
<body data-ng-keydown="$broadcast('keydown',$event)">
```

In my controller (child)

```
$scope.$on('keydown', function (event) {

})
```

I expected to see that event contained the same as $event but it does not. For example $event contains a keyCode field but event does not. What's wrong ?

I also tried this:

```
      $scope.callFunction = function (event) {
            $scope.$broadcast('keydown', event)
        }
```

Either way it seems when the keydown event is receive the parameter in the function (event) is not the same as the parameter sent in the broadcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second parameter to $on handler like that:

```
$scope.$on('keydown', function (event,myEvent) {
console.log(myEvent);
})
```

That should do it. The first event arg is a general event argument, and you do pass your own parameter so it goes second.